# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with 3.* Kernel?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, 16.04

I really don't know much about Kernels, so please excuse me if my questions sounds silly to you. :)

Is it possible to run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and install, for example a 3.19.0-* Kernel? I know it's possible on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS since they run those Kernels anyways, but can you do it on 16.04 LTS?

Comment: It is possible but not recommended. That may cause all sorts of trouble. I can see no reason to do it.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 server (32 bit) on a self-compiled Linux v3.19.8-ckt23 kernel without any problems. `Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.8-ckt23 i686)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 16.04 should be compatible with 3.19 since it would be used in 14.04, which can be upgraded to 16.04.

Some people are still using 3.19 due to issues such as https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/74

eldamir was able to manually install the 3.19 packages in this manner:

```
mkdir kernel
cd kernel
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/220635919/linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic_3.19.0-31.36~14.04.1_amd64.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/220668669/linux-headers-3.19.0-31_3.19.0-31.36~14.04.1_all.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/220635970/linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic_3.19.0-31.36~14.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-*
```

Note:

The kernels are related to hardware support, so the machines that upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 should be able to use the same kernel before the upgrade (at least for some time), since there was no change in the hardware. It is possible that a machine may have new hardware that is only supported in kernels newer than 3.x, but this does not mean that 16.04 is strictly incompatible with 3.x kernels, just that the machine will need to use a newer kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into doing this myself since I am finding 16.04 highly unstable. I installed 16.04 as a fresh install and get dependency errors trying to install the 3.19.0-31-generic:

> dpkg: error processing package linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic (--install):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/797223/617980) states that, though 16.04 may work with 3.19..., it works without any problem for those who have upgraded from 14.04. For anybody else it is likely much more hassle than it is worth if it will work at all. I will consider a fresh install of an older Ubuntu.

A kernel support page can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support).