# Install old kernel in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel, 16.04

My laptop can work perfectly on kernels up to 3.13.0-85 so is it possible to install the same in Ubuntu 16.04 without affecting it's performance?
And if yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

You will need Kernel 4.4 or newer.  I'm sure there is a way to run an older Kernel, however, it will likely break 16.04 since it relies on the newer Kernel functions.

A list of Ubuntu and Kernel OS/Kernel compatibilities can be found here

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support

Answer (score 1):

For 14.04 users who upgraded to 16.04, the 3.19 kernel (installed by 14.04) appears to remain usable. By similar reasoning, a 3.13 kernel may work as well even though it is not officially supported on the newer os (16.04).

You will need to download the relevant packages and install them manually via `dpkg`.